# Linux utility to draw character based chart or plot?

Tags: linux, command-line, charts, plot, 2d

This is what I so much look forward to knowing, and when it comes to my mind, I feel it so exiting and it is very convenient and useful. What it is? I don't know! but I want it use it in a linux **`command line environment`**, and get it to draw a `plot/chart` **without** a `X-Window` or any `GUI`.

for example, I have some data:

```
a, b, c, d, e
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

when I run the `utility`, I can have a `plot` directly displaying on the **`terminal`**:

```
a b c d e
- - - - -
  - - - -
    - - -
      - -
        -
```

The '-' can be any characters like '.' or whatever.

You know what I am saying! and I believe there is a good linux `tool` implemented out there, for more complex dataset, to draw 2-D plots/charts in terminal like many other GUI tools do in GUI environment, and it can even draw with colored characters! but what is it? I have been looking for it for months, but I don't know yet. Please give me a kick.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **gnuplot** with a **dumb terminal**: more informations [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/misc3-e.html).